# Problem building Position independent executable for android

Tags: android, c, openssl

I'm building openssl-1.0.1g for arm-linux-androideabi as described on wiki.openssl.org and my Android target needs to run position independent executables.  I added -fPIE and -pie to my Makefile and now I can see that Elf file type is DYN (Shared object file) but when I copy the file to the target and try to run it I get the following messages;

```
WARNING: linker: ./openssl has text relocations. This is wasting memory and prevents security hardening. Please fix.
CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE: cannot locate symbol "__exidx_end" referenced by "./openssl"...
```

Any ideas what these messages mean and how to resolve them is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Seems I just needed to link libc to define this symbol.